# Unable to compile a new Xcode project with error: unknown argument: '-frontend-parseable-output'

Tags: ios, xcode

I have upgraded Xcode to the latest Xcode 14.2 version and can no longer compile any project. File->New App project gives me same error.

Tried to install Xcode 14.3 beta - same issue.

MacOS: Ventura 13.2.1
Xcode: 14.2 and 14.3 Beta

```
SwiftCompile normal x86_64 Compiling\ SceneDelegate.swift /Users/<myuser>/Desktop/Sources/test8/test8/SceneDelegate.swift (in target 'test8' from project 'test8')
    cd /Users/<myuser>/Desktop/Sources/test8
    builtin-swiftTaskExecution -- /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-5.4.2-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c /Users/<myuser>/Desktop/Sources/test8/test8/ViewController.swift /Users/<myuser>/Desktop/Sources/test8/test8/AppDelegate.swift -primary-file /Users/<myuser>/Desktop/Sources/test8/test8/SceneDelegate.swift -emit-dependencies-path /Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test8.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test8.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SceneDelegate.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test8.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test8.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SceneDelegate.swiftdeps -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test8.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test8.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SceneDelegate.dia -target x86_64-apple-ios16.4-simulator -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.4.sdk -I /Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -no-color-diagnostics -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity\=checked -Onone -D DEBUG -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/<myuser>/Desktop/Sources/test8 -resource-dir /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-5.4.2-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift -enable-anonymous-context-mangled-names -Xcc -I/Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test8.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test8.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test8.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test8.build/test8-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test8.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test8.build/test8-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test8.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test8.build/test8-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test8.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test8.build/test8-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test8.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test8.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test8.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test8.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test8.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test8.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG\=1 -module-name test8 -frontend-parseable-output -target-sdk-version 16.4 -o /Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test8.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test8.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SceneDelegate.o -index-store-path /Users/<myuser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test8-ezstbxfhpbqmxjagjamtjhijljgh/Index.noindex/DataStore -index-system-modules
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from `/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-5.4.2-RELEASE.xctoolchain` it looks like you've installed an ancillary tool chain. Perhaps you forgot you'd done this.  Try uninstalling it or at least switching to the tool chain built into Xcode. (But uninstalling it would be better; it's probably too old and not compatible with this version of Xcode.)

Comment: Indeed! I have unstalled the toolchain and it now works as expected. Thanks a lot, you saved my day. And you are right, I do not recall installing this toolchain, and even removing xcode completely and installing i from scratch doesn't help. Only as you suggested, removing the toolchain from the folder specified solved the issue.